# Hard Drive issue?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

My laptop worked good, i bought it in September 2017, in November it started getting freeze and i not event could turn it off, when i tried opening the native console, i notice of this

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6OKF.jpg)

On December i took it to the support, they said is my operating system, i use Ubuntu. Yesterday in my desperate attempt to fix it i turn it on again, after a while i get freeze again and i get this message again.

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWkKC.jpg)

I was using Firefox, so i thing Firefox lost permissions

After that:

I Tried to install windows first and then Ubuntu, when i tried to install Ubuntu, it started giving me a message:

**> error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda input/output error**

**What can be the cause of this problem?
What solution should i consider?**

Pd: My apologies for my english

Comment: sound like a bad drive to me. Is it a Western Digital with an SSD buffer?

Comment: It is  a SATA Hard disk 1 TB,

Comment: who makes it? Western Digital had some issues with their hybrid 1TB drives.... I believe it was the WD Green drives. The 8GB solid state internal buffer fails.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ravery.  Your hard drive is failing.  I would back up what you can immediately and buy a new drive.  Maybe get a new drive first, then use it to back up what you can from the old one.  The less you use it, the more chance you have of eeking a little more data out of it.

Comment: Well i bought my laptop on september 2017, so there's no information :( , so i will buy a new hard drive. Thank you so much